# Performance issues while sending multiple XML events over HTTP

Tags: xml, jvm, wso2, wso2-cep

I'm running WSO2 CEP in a Ubuntu VM with 20GB RAM and 10 cores. I'm using HTTP event receiver type and sending data in xml format. My event xml file has multiple events. 1 event only has 1 attribute and it looks like this

```
<event>
<word>
string1000
</word>
</event>
```

1. When I'm sending 100000 events, in 1k(xml file has 1k events) batch, the CPU load % in JVM metrics in GUI shows 100% and it takes 3 minutes to process all events. I'm sending events to receiver via apache ab as

   ab -n 100 -c 1 -p data1000.xml -T text/plain ......./endpoints/xmlreceiver
2. When I'm sending 100000 events, in 10k batch(xml file has 10k events), the xml receiver metric shows no event received and jvm process shows 100% cpu utilization in VM, but the RAM and heap memory utilization is normal.

   ab -n 10 -c 1 -p data10000.xml -T text/plain ......./endpoints/xmlreceiver

I looked at this link for optimization and found optimization for JVM. I added -DentityExpansionLimit=100000 in wso2server.sh file, but still the performance is same in both cases.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Performance+Tuning+Recommendations

I have defined 2GB of heap memory. Parameters in data-bridge-config.xml are -

```
<workerThreads>10</workerThreads><maxEventBufferCapacity>20</maxEventBufferCapacity><eventBufferSize>10000</eventBufferSize>
```

My question is what can be the bottleneck in Case 1 and how can I solve it. In Case 2, what we have to do in order to process 10K (or more) xml event file ?

Himanshu